# Как передать данные через ajax на форму ExtJS

Tags: java, extjs

В контроллере делаю запрос через `Ext.Ajax.request`, после запроса в БД полученное отправляю обратно, присваивая полю `response` полученные данные. Суть в том что при попытке получить данные (`response.data`) со стороны ExtJS выдает ошибку `500 (Internal Server Error)`. Получается корректно отправить только простые типы вроде string. Как передать более сложную структуру, поскольку у меня приложение для тестирования, где каждый вопрос на двух языках и к каждому вопросу привязаны так же четыре вариантов ответов на двух языках. На ум приходит только сформировать json и распарсить его в js. Или есть еще способы передачи данных в extjs?

Вот немного кода. ExtJS:

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: baseRoot + 'portal/test',
        method: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function () {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Тест', 'Не удалось получить информацию о текущих вопросах');
        }
    });
```

Java, `execute` проверяет авторизацию пользователя:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
AjaxResponse getTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return execute(request, response, (user, request1, response1, ajaxResponse) -> {
      Questionnaire questionnaire = bean.getQuestionnaire(); 
      ajaxResponse.setCode(RESULT_CODE_SUCCESS);
      ajaxResponse.setSuccess(true);
      ajaxResponse.setData(questionnaire);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так полагаю, что ошибка 500 возникает не при получении response, а при отправке request. Откажитесь от GET в пользу POST, и как Вы и задумываете, используйте json. Особо парсить там ничего не нужно, все механизмы уже встроены, просто обращаетесь к полю JSON-ответа как свойству объекта response.
Например:

```
success: function(result) {
            alert('ID: ' + result.id
                    + ', Message: ' + result.message);
        }
```